# 401 error when trying to change spotify volume with spotipy

Tags: python, python-3.x, spotify, spotipy

I'm creating a personal assistant with python and wanted to add a spotify control feature
but I'm having trouble with changing my volume percentage and stuff with spotipy

I keep getting this error

```
  File "j:\coding stuff\PYTHONAI\plugins\spotify_plugin.py", line 51, in <module>
    SetVolume()
  File "j:\coding stuff\PYTHONAI\plugins\spotify_plugin.py", line 49, in SetVolume
    sp.volume(volume_percent, device_id=None)
  File "J:\coding stuff\PYTHONAI\venv\lib\site-packages\spotipy\client.py", line 1842, in volume
    self._put(
  File "J:\coding stuff\PYTHONAI\venv\lib\site-packages\spotipy\client.py", line 312, in _put
    return self._internal_call("PUT", url, payload, kwargs)
  File "J:\coding stuff\PYTHONAI\venv\lib\site-packages\spotipy\client.py", line 267, in _internal_call
    raise SpotifyException(
spotipy.exceptions.SpotifyException: http status: 401, code:-1 - https://api.spotify.com/v1/me/player/volume?volume_percent=10:  
 Permissions missing, reason: None
```

I tried everything to fix it, but nothing
I tried the scopes i could find n the spotify api docs and some stuff i saw from other code using spotipy

Here is how the code looks like

```
import spotipy
from spotipy.oauth2 import SpotifyOAuth
import os, sys
sys.path.append(os.path.dirname(os.path.dirname(os.path.abspath(__file__))))
from json_handler import *

username = spotifyUsername
playback = ""
scope = ""

sp = spotipy.Spotify(auth_manager=SpotifyOAuth(client_id=spotifyClientID,
                                                           client_secret=spotifyClientSecret,
                                                           redirect_uri="http://google.com/",
                                                           scope=""))

"""results = sp.search(q='black rover', limit=20)
for idx, track in enumerate(results['tracks']['items']):
    print(idx, track['name'])"""
#playback = sp.current_playback(market=None, additional_types=None)

def getCurrentPlay():
    scope = "user-read-currently-playing"
    #scopre = "user-read-currently-playing"
    playback = sp.currently_playing(market="ZA")
    #playback = sp.current_user_playing_track('name')
    print(playback)

def nextTrack():
    scope = "user-modify-playback-state"
    nextT = sp.next_track()

def prevTrack():
    scope = "user-modify-playback-state"
    prevT = sp.previous_track()

def Pause():
    scope = "user-modify-playback-state"
    sp.pause_playback()
    #sp.play

def Play():
    scope = "user-modify-playback-state"
    sp.start_playback()
    #sp.play

def SetVolume():
    scope = "user-modify-playback-state"
    volume_percent = 10
    sp.volume(volume_percent, device_id=None)

SetVolume()
#getCurrentPlay()
#CurrentPlay()
#print(playback)
```

Any help would be great!

Answer (score 1):

see the scopes on the spotify docs: https://developer.spotify.com/documentation/general/guides/authorization/scopes

you need to have `user-modify-playback-state` in your scope